# Bind data from Ajax post to model passed to controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to update a document using an Ajax call, but I have been unsuccessful with binding the data from the Ajax call to the model passed to the controller.

What am I doing wrong here?

I have also tried changing the definition of the controller to expect a string, which avoids the below NullReferenceException, but the string is passed as null.

**Request Payload**

```
{"model":{"Text":"Test","LastUpdated":null,"TrainingSentiment":"Test","Sentiment":"Test","SentimentScore":"-1","Entities":[{"Start":0,"End":0,"Value":"Test","Orth":"Test","Label":"Test"}]}}
```

**Preview**

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document.get_AttachmentsLink()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.PropertyHelper.CallNullSafePropertyGetter[TDeclaringType,TValue](Func`2 getter, Object target)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.DefaultComplexObjectValidationStrategy.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.VisitChildren(IValidationStrategy strategy)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.VisitComplexType()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation.ValidationVisitor.Visit(ModelMetadata metadata, String key, Object model)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.DefaultControllerArgumentBinder.<BindModelAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.DefaultControllerArgumentBinder.<BindArgumentsCoreAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.BrowserLinkMiddleware.<ExecuteWithFilter>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

**Ajax**

```
var modelObj = {
    model: {
        Text: "Test",
        LastUpdated: null,
        TrainingSentiment: "Test",
        Sentiment: "Test",
        SentimentScore: "-1",
        Entities: [
            {
                Start: 0,
                End: 0,
                Value: "Test",
                Orth: "Test",
                Label: "Test"
            }
        ]
    }
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/Tweets/DocumentUpdateAjax',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(modelObj),
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (response) {
        console.log("Success!");

        /** Replace the partial view with html contents from the response. **/
        $("#updateDocumentPartialView").html(response);

    },
    failure: function (response) {
        console.log("Failure!");

        /** Dump the JSON string to the console. **/
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.log("Error!");

        /** Dump the JSON string to the console. **/
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DocumentUpdateAjax(TrainingModel model)
{
    ....
}
```

**Model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TextualAnalytics.Models
{
    public class TrainingModel : Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document
    {

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "last_updated")]
        public DateTime? LastUpdated { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "training_sentiment")]
        public string TrainingSentiment { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "sentiment")]
        public string Sentiment { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "sentiment_score")]
        public string SentimentScore { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "entities")]
        public List<Entity> Entities { get; set; }

        public class Entity
        {

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "start")]
            public long Start { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "end")]
            public long End { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
            public string Value { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "orth")]
            public string Orth { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "label")]
            public string Label { get; set; }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: In .NET Core, you must add [FromBody] attribute before the action method's model parameter to bind the Ajax post. ...DocumentUpdateAjax([FromBody] TrainingModel model)

Answer (score 0):

The `[FromBody]` Attribute gives the ASP.NET Core Framework the clue to bind the data of the request body to the model by using the serializer. By default the framework binds form fields. Try to change the controller method to

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult DocumentUpdateAjax([FromBody] TrainingModel model)
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: The above change results in: POST http://localhost:50991/Tweet/DocumentUpdateAjax 415 (Unsupported Media Type) I would assume this is because: Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8. What should this be?

Comment: The Content-Type of the Post has to be application/json. Somehow your data gets submitted like a form;although your $.ajax call has set "application/json". ASP.NET Core MVC rejects the call with 415 because FromBody delegates model binding to the configured serializers (JSON is enabled by default); if no suitable serializer is found (like this case) 415 is returned. So the problem is now to find the reason, why no json is posted.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are sending the data with normal POST. Try to wrap all your code like this:

```
$('#buttonId').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // and all of your ajax and js codes...
});
```

And change the `dataType` attribute's value "`html`" to "`json`" in the ajax objext.